# Nome no index de um array

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso criar um array ou objeto, mas com nome/index dinâmico, tipo este do exemplo, porém o nome deve vir de uma variável:

```
var1 = "testeIndex";

var obj = {
    var1 : {
        'elemento1' : 'dado1',
        'elemento2' : 'dado2'
    },
    var2 : {
        'elemento1' : 'dado1',
        'elemento2' : 'dado2'
    },
    var3 : {
        'elemento1' : 'dado1',
        'elemento2' : 'dado2'
    },
};
```

Porém, quando boto o nome da variável, mesmo sem aspas, o index recebe o nome literal da variável.

É possível fazer o que estou tentando fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente com

```
var obj = {
    [var1] : {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Referência:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript

Segundo o link, essa notação é suportada a partir do ECMAScript 2015.
Em versões anteriores é necessário construir o objeto passo-a-passo, com:

```
obj = {};
obj[var1] = { /*...*/ };
// etc.
```

Ver também:
[Compatibilidade com navegadores:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) (é a linha Computed property names)

Comment: Seria legal inserir informações sobre compatibilidade, como por exemplo a sessão [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) da MSN (é a linha _Computed property names_)

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!